# Split time difference into blocks of hours from 0:00 to 23:00

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following columns, that represent the beginning and end time of an event:

```
               fh_ini              fh_end
1 2015-12-07 00:00:00   2015-12-07 00:00:00
2 2015-12-07 00:00:00   2015-12-07 09:52:46
3 2015-12-07 09:20:13   2015-12-07 09:20:19
4 2015-12-07 09:20:22   2015-12-07 09:36:38
5 2015-12-07 09:40:49   2015-12-07 09:41:05
6 2015-12-07 09:45:12   2015-12-07 09:46:05
```

I would like to split the time difference betwen fh_end and fh_ini in blocks of 1 hour each, and count the number of minutes in each block.

The aim is to calculate the total time for all events and for each block (for instance, the block between 00:00 and 01:00 am, etc.).

I'm pretty new to R and I'm not sure whether I can actually do this using existing functions or if I should code something (with loops?) that does it.

The result I'm expecting would be as follows (from Excel). The gap from 3:00 to 4:00 in the 2nd row would count only 42 minutes and 37 secs.

```
                                       0:00  1:00  2:00  3:00        4:00
07/12/2015 1:00:00  07/12/2015 3:00:00   0     1     1     0           0
07/12/2015 0:00:00  07/12/2015 3:42:37   1     1     1   0,710277778   0
```

If I had just 2 rows, like the example, the result total event time (in hours) for each block would be:

```
0:00  1:00  2:00     3:00      4:00
  1     2      2   0,710277778   0
```

I wonder if factorising the time difference is the key to creating this blocks, but I've tried both creating a factor of 1 day in 24 blocks and factorising the difftime in the same fashion and I don't quite know what to do next. I'm not sure if there's any other way of getting the result that doesn't involve to factorise the difftime, anyway.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do your events ever wrap around midnight? Or are they always contained within a single day?

Comment: And do your dates matter, or are you only interested in comparing times? If your dates do matter, is each time block associated with a specific day as well as time?

Comment: No, the dates don't actually matter, indeed. It's the times what I really have to manage. These data comes from a daily file that might aggregate events from different days, but I should just use those within the file's date minus 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chron` package provides utilities for working with dates and times. In particular, you can make use of the `times` function, which converts strings of the format `hh:mm:ss` into `times` objects. Data in this format can be added and subtracted, and compared using functions like `<`, `>`, `max`, and `min`. Try playing around with it to get a sense of how everything works!

#### Parsing your data

You'll want to start by turning those `fh_ini` and `fh_end` columns from strings into time objects. I'll drop the dates and focus only on the times:

```
library(chron)

to_times <- function(vec) {
  str_times <- sapply(strsplit(dtimes, ' '), `[`, 2)
  times(str_times)
}

your_data$fh_ini_times <- to_times(your_data$fh_ini)
your_data$fh_end_times <- to_times(your_data$fh_end)
```

Your data are already conveniently formatted, so all I'm doing here is splitting your strings on spaces to break them into a list of date and time pairs, grabbing the second element of each entry in the list, and then converting then from strings to times.

#### Checking blocks

The way I'd do this is to write a function that takes a start time, an end time, and a block, and returns the amount of overlap. I've written an example below - I've made it a little on the verbose side for the sake of readability and to clearly show what you can do with the `times` data type.

```
block_check <- function(range_start, range_end, block_start) {
  start_check <- (range_start < block_start + times("01:00:00"))
  end_check <- (range_end > block_start)
  if (start_check & end_check) {
    o_start <- max(block_start, range_start)
    o_end <- min(block_start + times("01:00:00"), range_end)
    return(o_end - o_start)
  } else {
    return(times("00:00:00"))
  }
}
```

If you break this function down, I'm just (1) checking that the range defined by `start_time` and `end_time` overlaps the given 1 hour block, and if it does returning how much overlap there is.

Once you have this function, you can use `mapply` to apply it to each start/end time pair in your data set, like so:

```
z <- mapply(FUN = block_check, your_data$fh_ini_times, your_data$fh_end_times, 
            MoreArgs = list(block_start = times("01:00:00")))
your_data[,"1:00"] <- times(z)
```

#### Doing it all at once

It's clumsy and boring having to do the above to each of your 24 time blocks. If you want to get fancy and do everything all at once rather than for each block separately, you can loop over a list of blocks. Here, I've created a vector of block start times (as strings) using the `stringr` package, and then apply the function from before to each element (as a time) in turn (using the string version of the time to name the resulting column of the data frame).

```
library(stringr)
blocks <- str_c(as.character(0:23), ":00:00")
f <- function(block) { 
  z <- mapply(FUN = block_check, your_data$fh_ini_times, your_data$fh_end_times, 
              MoreArgs = list(block_start = block)) 
  times(z)
}
for (block in blocks) {
  your_data[, block] <- f(times(block))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have tried the solution on the daily event register and it gives out just the information I need (though it takes a while, it's a lot of data).

Comment: @Emma Also, since you mention the long time to evaluate: if speedier performance  is a big concern for you, you may want to check out data.table, which is a very popular package for fast calculations and manipulations with large amounts of data.